# I've loaded a yaml file with `!ENV SOME_VAR` and replaced the string with the value. How do I save the original string and not the changed string?

Tags: python, yaml

I'm using python 3.x and pyyaml. I'm not married to pyyaml if I need to replace it.

There are a number of questions (with answers) on how to replace a value in a yaml file with the value of an environment variable.

E.g. `db_password: !ENV DB_PASSWORD` becomes `db_password: s00p3rs3kr3t`.

The user and the program can make changes to other values (e.g., user sets db_table with cli option, program sets generated hash value).

I want to save those changes without saving the value of the environment variable for `db_password`.

A simplified example of what I have looks like the following code.

```py
def my_regex:
  return regex

def resolve_env_vars:
  # replace string with environment variable value

loader = yaml.SafeLoader
loader.add_implicit_resolver('!ENV', my_regex(), None)
loader.add_constructor('!ENV', resolve_env_vars)

with open(yamlfile, 'r',) as raw:
  cfg = yaml.load(raw, Loader=loader)
```

While this works fine for loading the value into the resulting dict, I need to figure out some way of noting the original value and which key it goes with.

I have stepped through the entire process with `pudb` and I cannot find a way to restore the original value when writing the config file. By the time the code gets to `resolve_env_vars` the associated key (e.g., `db_password` in the example above) is not accessible.

How do I save `db_password: !ENV DB_PASSWORD` instead of `db_password: s00p3rs3kret` when writing the data back to the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the tag to cause the creation of an instance that behaves like a string, but has the original
environment variable tucked onto it, so it can be found at dump time:

```py
import sys
import os
import ruamel.yaml


yaml_str = """\
db_password: !ENV DB_PASSWORD
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.default_flow_style = False


@yaml.register_class
class EnvStr(str):
    yaml_tag = '!ENV'

    def __new__(cls, env_var):
        ret_val = str.__new__(cls, os.environ.get(env_var, f'ENV "{env_var}" NOT SET'))
        ret_val.env_var = env_var
        return ret_val

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        return cls(node.value)

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, node.env_var)


os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'] = 's00p3rs3kr3t'

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(f'The password is "{data["db_password"]}" (without the double quotes). Keep it safe!')
print('\nYAML dump:')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
The password is "s00p3rs3kr3t" (without the double quotes). Keep it safe!

YAML dump:
db_password: !ENV DB_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Thank you. This broke a logjam for me.