# In python, when loading a yaml file, is it possible to delay evaluation of a value until a specific *different* key is set?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I use `python` and `ruamel.yaml` to load a configuration file. I am currently allowing a [`!NETRC`][1] entry evaluated from the user's `.netrc` file when a password or token is needed.

This is working ok, but it can sometimes be frustrating when some functions take a while before attempting to connect and fail.

However, to evaluate the netrc tag, I need the host entry (it should be a URL, but netrc allows any string in the host field), which is a sibling key in the yaml file.

The relevant part of my yaml file looks like this.

```yaml
connect:
  url: https://my.company/path/to/service
  login: mylogin
  token: !NETRC
```

I need `token` to **not** be evaluated until `url` is and a way to access that value.

Am I expecting too much? Is there a way to do this with ruamel.yaml?

A simplified example of the code looks like the following:

```py
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.default_flow_style = False

class NetrcTag(str):
    yaml_tag = '!NETRC'
    def __new__(cls, value):
        newvalue = str.__new__(cls, '!NETRC')
        # newvalue.netrctag = load_netrc(cfg, url value goes here) <----
        newvalue.netrctag = value
        return newvalue

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        return cls(node.value)

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, represented, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, node.netrctag)
```

[1]: Thanks @Anthon! [I've loaded a yaml file with `!ENV SOME_VAR` and replaced the string with the value. How do I save the original string and not the changed string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75022789/491894)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating `NetrcTag` the url value is not necessarily known to `ruamel.yaml`. It should in your example, but you should not rely on that, and would require digging into the ruamel.yaml internals.

Instead I recommend extending the `NetrcTag` class with a method `set_url`
that passes in the url and retrieves the actual value. Tricky might be the actual syntax of updating `str` when not done from `__new__()`.

This doesn't help with the delay getting the data using the URL might cause. You cannot call `set_url` until after loading, but if you are not using the value until later in the program you might use multiprocessing or asynchronous calls for the retrieval, and it might be done until you need the value.

Comment: I'm already doing the netrc tag resolution after the config is read. I didn't explain that very well. In any case, it sounds like it's more work than I'm willing to expend on a small niggle.